# How to create this sort of motion/liquefy/hallucinogenic optical effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

I'm a photographer/designer looking to hone my skills and I recently looked at the picture below, and especially in the corners, I was wondering how could I achieve the same look/vibe/effect with Photoshop.

[image: picture]

Answer (score 3):

If you make an irregular selection with the Lasso tool, then feather it, then invert the selection, you can then apply a radial blur zoom effect.

[image]

Here's the result

[image]

Comment: I wish I could upvote you but the website says I havn't got enough "reputation" :'))

Comment: you're a legend! thank you so much!

Comment: @Raphael  Don't worry about it. I'm not here for votes. ;)

Comment: @Raphael welcome to the community. You can mark the answer as accepted later on, check [ask] and take the [tour] to learn more about the site :)